# Using subexpression with & in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am completely new to powershell.

I have a requirement to have a set of commands as a subexpression $() because I want the output of the command to be sent to Out-Host and without $() the if loops create an issue.
Now there might also be a possibility that the command has filenames with spaces and to handle that we append `&` before the file name in command.

Bacially, $(& file_name) | Out-Host fails saying & here is invalid.

How to go about using $() with &

Comment: Please show a full command that exhibits the problem - the example you're giving works fine (and wouldn't require `$(...)`). There are no restrictions on what you can place inside `$(...)`.

Comment: Also: When you say that something didn't work, you have to say _how_ it didn't work. (You don't give an example, and you don't say how doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

Works ok for me.  You'll need to supply a counterexample.  In this case you couldn't pipe from "if" without $() or &{}.

```
$( If (1 -eq 1) { & echo hi } ) | out-host > file
hi
```

```
# no output until it's finished
$( If (1 -eq 1) { & 'c:\program files\internet explorer\iediagcmd' } ) | 
  out-host > file
```